# How to detect if user force stop my service

Tags: android, service, applicationmanager

I need to detect if the user force stop my service (from application manager).
In onDestroy() I need to implement different function when service stopped by the user("force stop") or by the system(low memory)/reboot.

Comment: If the system force stops a service due to low memory `onDestroy()` is never called. I suspect the same happens when a user clicks "force stop" button which is (not 100% sure - Settings app sources should be browsed) equivalent to `am force-stop` command. Probably checking if your service is alive would be the right direction. Lots of posts on that can be found on SO.

Comment: Thanx, I still need to distinguish between "force stop" by the user or phone shutdown. If isfinishing() method happens in both cases, it means that the only method I have is to register a shutdownreceiver to detect shutdown?